PDF.js lost Event Listener after new file opened using open method
I'm using PDF.js
Adding references straightforward
    <link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="/locale/locale.json"> <script src="build/pdf.js" type="module"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/viewer.css">
I wanted to remove a specific page using another plugin name pdf-lib
I do the following
1- Read PDF File as Base64 from PDF Viewer
async function ReadPDFFromViewer() {
            var pdfFileBytes = await PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.saveDocument();
            var b64encoded = _arrayBufferToBase64(pdfFileBytes);
            return b64encoded;
        }
        function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
            var binary = '';
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var len = bytes.byteLength;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            return window.btoa(binary);
        }

2- Load and remove targeted page using pdf-lib
            var currentFilePDFBase64 = await ReadPDFFromViewer();
            let pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(currentFilePDFBase64);
            pdfDoc.removePage(currentPage)
            var pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

3- Reopen the edited file onto PDF Viewer
            PDFViewerApplication.open({ data: pdfBytes });
            PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.refresh(false, "");

Until this code it works correctly
The problem
After reopen the edited PDF, The action Open on editor no longer being loaded new selected file
When I click Open and select new file after that no file appears on Viewer
enter image description here
I Read the events inside viewer.js and reach this lines of codes file
                        var fileInput = this._openFileInput = document.createElement("input");
                        fileInput.id = "fileInput";
                        fileInput.hidden = true;
                        fileInput.type = "file";
                        fileInput.value = null;
                        document.body.append(fileInput);
                        fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
                            debugger;
                            const {
                                files
                            } = evt.target;
                            if (!files || files.length === 0) {
                                return;
                            }
                            eventBus.dispatch("fileinputchange", {
                                source: this,
                                fileInput: evt.target
                            });
                        });

I notice after doing previous actions the listener stop triggered
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (evt)
I tried to add event listener again but the PDF Viewer still no file being loaded

I solve this problem after this code
    PDFViewerApplication.open({ data: pdfBytes });
    PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.refresh(false, "");

I have to add the event listener again by using PDFViewerApplication
  var fileInput = PDFViewerApplication._openFileInput = document.createElement("input");
            fileInput.id = "fileInput";
            fileInput.hidden = true;
            fileInput.type = "file";
            fileInput.value = null;
            document.body.append(fileInput);
            fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {

                const {
                    files
                } = evt.target;
                if (!files || files.length === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.eventBus.dispatch("fileinputchange", {
                    source: PDFViewerApplication,
                    fileInput: evt.target
                });
            }); 


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
